# Error on commit - How to increase Docker default container size when using Docker Toolbox and Windows 7

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-container

I'm running Docker on Windows 7, so Docker runs within a Virtual Box.

I've got an issue where I've got an Oracle image which has then had a database restored to it, pushing the image size up to 7.5 gigs. I want to do a docker commit on this, but I'm getting an out of space error when I do the commit.

I've seen a lot of posts on changing the default container size, but I'm not sure if this is possible with aufs, or how to change to a different file system type when running on Windows 7/VirtualBox.

Does anyone know how to increase the default container size in this environment ?

```
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /u01/app/oracle/oradata/XE/support.dbf: no space left on device
```

Docker info:

```
    Containers: 1
 Running: 1
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 72
Server Version: 17.10.0-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 127
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 0351df1c5a66838d0c392b4ac4cf9450de844e2d
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.4.93-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 17.10.0-ce (TCL 7.2); HEAD : 34fe485 - Wed Oct 18 17:16:34 UTC 2017
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7.79GiB
Name: default
ID: 2NWU:57WJ:4QAP:EBMY:MMF2:JFWA:IBWU:THGO:A4VD:SGVW:YQBP:MP2N
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 24
 Goroutines: 35
 System Time: 2017-12-06T09:33:14.736388742Z
 EventsListeners: 2
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default size for a docker machine is 20GB, you can double-check by running `docker-machine inspect default`. This size can be configured when creating the machine from the cli. You can recreate the default machine and set the size as follows:

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-disk-size "400000" default
```

You can also edit the file `C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh` to set default values for size and ram for created machines.

Comment: Is the above the default for the the VM ? I'm talking about the default for containers that run within the VM.

Comment: Containers don't have a limit by default, they can use all the VM resources. The problem in your case, is that the background VM which runs on docker for mac has a disk size of 20GB and is running out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for that -  perfect explanation.